# How to transform mouse to world coordinates?

Tags: directx, mouse, slimdx

I have the a SlimDX Matrix for each of the world, view and projection transforms. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb147302(v=vs.85).aspx the projection transform leaves coordinates in the (-1,1)^3 cube.

I thought that by translating the mouse position relative to the render target into projection space (i.e. scale it into the (-1,1) range and fix it at -1 in the z axis) and then applying the inverted worldviewprojection.

The code below shows my attempt. My test is to run the app and zoom in and out using the mouse wheel and see if the printed X coordinate changes while keeping the mouse cursor over the left edge of the window - it doesn't so something must be wrong somewhere.

```
form.MouseMove += (obj, eargs) =>
        {
            SlimDX.Matrix worldview = SlimDX.Matrix.Multiply(SlimDX.Matrix.Identity, viewMatrix);
            SlimDX.Matrix worldviewprojection = SlimDX.Matrix.Multiply(worldview, projectionMatrix);
            worldviewprojection.Invert();

            var pointX = (float)((2.0 * ((float)eargs.Location.X) / (float)form.Width) - 1.0f);
            var pointY = (float)((2.0 * (((float)eargs.Location.Y) / (float)form.Height)) - 1.0f) * -1.0f;
            var mouseInProjectionSpace = new Vector4(pointX, pointY, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            var mouseInWorldSpace = Vector4.Transform(mouseInProjectionSpace, worldviewprojection);
            Console.WriteLine(mouseInWorldSpace);
        };

        form.MouseWheel += (_, __) =>
            {
                if (__.Delta > 0)
                    cam.Z /= 2.0f;
                else
                    cam.Z *= 2.0f;
                viewMatrix = GetView(cam);
                Console.WriteLine("zzz="+cam.Z);
            };
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: How does an example of `mouseInWorldSpace` look like? Have you divided it by it's w-component? Can you try it with z=0 instead of -1?

Answer (score 0):

your z is wrong, since in projective space z is 0 (near plane) to 1 (far plane)

So it does:

```
Vector2 mouse = //Normalized as -1 to 1 (as you did)
Vector3 orig = new Vector3(mouse.X,mouse.Y,0.0f);
Vector3 far = new Vector3(mouse.X,mouse.Y,1.0f);

//This gets mouse position on near plane
Vector3 origin = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(orig,worldviewprojectioninverse);

//This gets mouse position on far plane
Vector3 posfar = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(far,worldviewprojectioninverse);
```